# All Google Play subscriptions are refunded after trial period

Tags: android, subscription, android-billing

I am developing Android app with `com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.1`. My subscription has the following parameters.

> Billing period: 3 months
>
> Free trial period: 3 days
>
> Introductory price: -
>
> Grace period: 3 days

But all of them (>100) become refunded 3 days after successful purchase. I don't understand the reason.

Here is a screenshot of typical order history:
[image: order history]

Users ask why it is happening. I don't think all of them choose to return money.

My BillingManager class:

```
public class BillingManager implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {

private BillingClient billingClient;
private final List<Purchase> purchases = new ArrayList<>();

public BillingManager(Context context) {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    startConnection();
}

void startConnection() {
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            final int responseCode = billingResult.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                queryPurchases();
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            retry();
        }
    });
}

void queryPurchases() {
    PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(SkuType.SUBS);
    List<Purchase> cachedPurchaseList = purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
    onPurchasesUpdated(cachedPurchaseList);
}

@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
    final int responseCode = billingResult.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        onPurchasesUpdated(purchasesList);
    } else if (responseCode == BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        handleCanceledPurchase();
    } else {
        handleUnknownResponse();
    }
}

private void onPurchasesUpdated(@Nullable List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
    purchases.clear();
    if (purchasesList != null) {
        for (Purchase purchase : purchasesList) {
            processPurchase(purchase);
        }
    }

    notifyListener();
}

private void processPurchase(Purchase purchase) {
    if (purchase.getPurchaseState() != PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        return;
    }

    if (!verify(purchase)) {
        return;
    }

    purchases.add(purchase);
}

public boolean shouldDoStuff() {
    if (purchases.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            if (purchase.getPurchaseState() != PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                continue;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

PS: The app verifies purchase signature locally and statistics says that results are positive.

Comment: Have you acknowledged the purchase as described in the documentation here? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge

Comment: @jontro damn it! I thought subscriptions shouldn't be acknowledged... Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for upgrading to the Play Billing Library 2.+. With respect to acknowledgement, you are required to acknowledge both subscriptions and non-consumable in-app products. During acknowledgement, and only during acknowledgement, you may optionally set a payload. The payload that you set will subsequently be returned when you query Purchases.

An important note about consumable products. You are not required to acknowledge consumable products. But if you do choose to acknowledge them (for whatever reason) and if -- further -- you submit a payload at the time of acknowledgement: then you are required to submit that same payload when you call `consumeAsync` on Android.

Also you may acknowledge either through Android or through the server api.